# Interpretar html en una relacion ternaria en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo un if ternario en laravel y si la relación ternaria es true me gustaría mostrar una etiqueta span con contenido.

```
{{$product->novelty ? "<span>Novedad</span>" : ""}}
```

Actualmente se me muestra asi, quiero que el span me lo interprete como una etiqueta html

[image: Actualmente se me muestra asi]

Comment: ¿Para qué usar un ternario si no vas a mostrar nada cuando el resultado sea `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por qué no usas un condicional para mostrar o no el span?

```
@if($product->novelty)
  <span>Novedad</span>
@endif
```